# Charts.js destroy previous data and update

Tags: javascript, date, hover, chart.js, destroy

It seems like this is a common issue with charts.js. I created a site that allows you to choose a date. When you click a specific date a line chart updates given that dates' csv file. If you then go and click on a new date the chart.js line chart updates but if you over over the data it briefly displays the previous dates data.

I have seen a bunch of questions on this before and have tried to use the .destroy() along with updating the chart but every time I add this to any point of the code, the canvas simply gets destroyed and a chart is never created.

HTML:

```
<div class="chooseGame">
   <button onclick="dropDownFunction()" class="gameDropDown">Select a Game Date & Time</button>
   <div id="dropdown" class="dates"></div>
</div>

JS:

function dropDownFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick =
function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.gameDropDown')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dates");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}


$(document).on("click", ".test",function(e){
var selectedDate= ($(this).text())

document.getElementById("today").innerText = selectedDate;


var cFD = document.getElementById('Canvas').getContext('2d');
var backgroundFD = document.getElementById('fDChart').style.background='white';

FirstData = new Chart(cFD, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: fdgameArray,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'New',
          backgroundColor: "#f15a22",
          borderColor: "#f15a22",
          data: fdNewData,
          fill: false,
      },
        {
          label: 'Completed',
          backgroundColor: "#004684",
          borderColor: "#004684",
          data: fdCompData,
          fill: false,
        },
          {
            label: 'Oustanding',
            fontColor: '#a7b1c2',
            borderColor: '#a7b1c2',
            data: fdOutData,
            fill: false,
          }]
  },
  options: {
        responsive: true,
        title:{
          display:false,
          text: 'Delta Club',
          fontSize: 15,
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
          fontColor: '#004684'
        },
        tooltips:{
          mode: "index",
          intersect: false,
        },
        hover:{
          mode:"nearest",
          intersect: true
        },
        scales:{
          xAxes:[{
            display: true,
            ticks:{
              fontColor:'#004684',
              fontSize: 10
            },
            scaleLabel:{
              display: true,
              labelString: "Time",
              fontColor:'#004684',
              fontSize: 12
            }
          }],
          yAxes:[{
            display: true,
            ticks:{
              fontColor:'#004684',
              fontSize: 10,
              beginAtZero: true,
              steps: 10,
              stepValue: 1,
              Max: 100
            },
            scaleLabel:{
              display: true,
              labelString: "# Orders",
              fontColor:'#004684',
              fontSize: 12
            }
          }]
        }

    }})
  };
```

Whenever you change the date and hover over the chart, the previous date's data is displayed and then reverts back to current selected date. I want current data displayed always.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to adjust the following and now I am all set:

```
var cFD = document.getElementById('Canvas').getContext('2d');
var backgroundFD = document.getElementById('firstDataChart').style.background='white';
if(window.chart && window.chart !== null){
        window.chart.destroy();
    }
window.chart = new Chart(cFD, {...})
```